# Trying to do heroku login or netlify login in git bash, getting this error "Error: unable to verify the first certificate"

Tags: heroku, ssl-certificate, command-line-interface, netlify

```
$ heroku login
heroku: Press any key to open up the browser to login or q to exit:
Error: unable to verify the first certificate

$ netlify login
Logging into your Netlify account...
 »   FetchError: request to https://api.netlify.com/api/v1/oauth/tickets?client_id=d6f37de6614df7ae58664cfca524744d73807a377f5ee71f1a254f78412e3750 failed, reason: unable to verify the first certificate
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my problem by just renewing my antivirus.It actually needed a valid and trusted server certificate which was issued by the antivirus itself.